# Can't fix error using codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just new using codeIgniter and I wanted to create a simple login with sign up and session.

Here's my code...

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginVerify extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('userModel', '', TRUE);
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_this_database');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
        else {
            redirect('home', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function this_database($password) {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $result=$this->user->login($username, $password);
        if($result) {
            $sess_array=array();
            foreach($result as $row) {
                $sess_array=array('id'=>$row->id, 'username'=>$row->username);
                $this->session->set_userdata(logged_in, $sess_array);   
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message(this_database, 'Invalid username or password');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I don't know why I'm still receiving error when trying to run this program.

Comment: This would be nice if you will indicate the error that you encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling db queries on callback try your method part in after validation success also create a alias for usermodel. also check you have already included session library.
Also you left syntax errors so try my full code:-

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginVerify extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('userModel', 'user');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
        else {
            $username=$this->input->post('username');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $result=$this->user->login($username, $password);
            if($result) {
                $sess_array=array();
                foreach($result as $row) {
                    $sess_array=array('id'=>$row->id, 'username'=>$row->username);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);   
                }
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('this_database', 'Invalid username or password');
                redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: yes my library included here. Error move to this line $this->session->set_userdata(logged_in, $sess_array);

Comment: check updated it will be  $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

Comment: wow. thanks. I got it. I can now proceed creating account. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Oh I see, here wait. Thanks again!

Comment: simple for upvote click up arrow of answer or for accept question click on right button of answer

Comment: is this election page? and your running candidate to say that accept or vote your answer?

Comment: @user3709308 i am not saying to accept me i suggest

Comment: @user3709308 if you newbie you also need this suggestion. not the same meaning i have 2 yr exp on stack so i know this thing

Answer (score 2):

i think because of this

```
    else {
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
        //means you are going to controller named home, but your controller name is LoginVerify
    }
```

guess it will solve your problem

Comment: In ci redirect('home') means home controller it will redirect home controller home/index

Comment: there are so many errors in code like $this->session->set_userdata(logged_in, $sess_array);

Comment: I have code in Home. That's part of my View in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
```

Answer (score -2):

try to change

> $this->load->model('userModel', '', TRUE);

to

> $this->load->model('userModel', 'user');

and better remove php close tag at the end of the script